# How to get protocol(http/https) of the incoming request from the laravel HTTP request class?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my new application API, I have to check the request from the third party URL's should be in https. If it is not https, I have to return the message as "connection is not secure'. Can anyone help me?

Comment: A simple google search should help you

Comment: @SathishkumarR i thint it would be better to redirect to secure url automaticaly, no showing the message, dont you think?

Comment: @Autista_z It is just an API. It will validate the request and register the user in my application. Then It will return the response with URL to access with access token which expires in 5 minutes.

Comment: upvote because @SathishkumarR asking for laravel core function to check.

Answer (score 31):

Here you are:

```
Determining If The Request Is Over HTTPS
Using Request::secure()

if (request()->secure())
{
  //
}
```

If your host are behind a load balancer, use Request getScheme instead

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Comment: getScheme() method returns the protocol of the request.

Comment: this uses a port detection method. on some load balancers (heroku, aws), this will fail even if https because some of the requests done behind the load balancer are on port 80 instead of 443. I ended up having to use a https string check as well.

Comment: Error: `Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::secure() should not be called statically `

Comment: @realtebo use `request()->secure()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Daniel Tran's answer is correct just for information HTTPS type requests have an extra field **HTTPS** on requests. Sometimes this field can be equal to *off* too but nothing else.

so you can just write a code like

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off') { 
  doSomething();
}
```

Laravel Request Class also inherited something totally similar from symphony. Which You can find under;

> vendor/symfony/http-foundatiton/Request.php

```
public function isSecure()
    {
        if ($this->isFromTrustedProxy() && self::$trustedHeaders[self::HEADER_CLIENT_PROTO] && $proto = $this->headers->get(self::$trustedHeaders[self::HEADER_CLIENT_PROTO])) {
            return in_array(strtolower(current(explode(',', $proto))), array('https', 'on', 'ssl', '1'));
        }

        $https = $this->server->get('HTTPS');

        return !empty($https) && 'off' !== strtolower($https);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

From Laravel Request Class use `getSchemeAndHttpHost()` method

```
{{ Request::getSchemeAndHttpHost() }}
```

Returns for example :

- `http://example.com` or
- `http://192.0.0.1` or
- `https://example.com`

returns `protocol/domain` name

Answer (score 0):

```
Request::getScheme()
```

return "http" or https"

if you want get the protocol string.